# How to use the Excel INDIRECT function more effectively in fetching data from multiple sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a workbook in which the first worksheet is the summary of subsequent worksheets in the same workbook. The Summary sheet should fetch data from the other sheets in a table in the workbook. The table has Monday to Friday - five days as columns and monthly dates as row headers e.g. 1-Jul-23, 2-Jul-23.....31-Jul-23. There are 5 worksheets each named - Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, and Friday (from Columns C to G). Each worksheet has a table with only one column viz., “Batch no.” and rows (from row 10 onward) for each date of the month. Whenever any of the batch no. is filled against any date of the month in one or more sheets, the same value should get fetched in the summary sheet table in the appropriate cell. Whenever the sheet cell is not updated with a value, the corresponding summary cell also should show blank and not zero. How to do this efficiently using the Excel Indirect function?[The workbook link described here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LrK67AWmPtuJ9Ecci6SMnzZWRj-XJbDd/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=107602068659746725053&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Comment: Do you mean `=LET(h,HSTACK(Monday:Friday!C10:C22),IF(h="","",h))` ?

Answer (score 0):

If your dates are consistent like in your file, you could use this:

```
=LET(h,HSTACK(Monday:Friday!C10:C22),
     IF(h="","",h))
```

otherwise you could use:

```
=LET(i,INDEX(HSTACK(Monday:Friday!C10:C22),
             XMATCH(B10:B22,B10:B22),
             XMATCH(C9:G9,C9:G9)),
IF(i="","",i))
```

Comment: Very nice approach with `HSTACK()`