# MATCH(): How do I pull information from multiple worksheets in a known column using a list of worksheet names?

Tags: excel-formula, match

I'm trying to extract information from cells in another sheet and I need to repeat this for 400 sheets. A basic template has been applied so I know what column this bit of data lies in. I've got a working formula that finds the row this bit of information sits in as this varies sheet by sheet. I have a list of all the sheets names and would like to feed of of this to save a lot of time.

This is the formula I have.

```
=INDIRECT("'" & SUBSTITUTE($D14," ","") & "'!" & $K$8& MATCH("Total", 'CAI001'!$F:$F,0))
```

The substitute takes the space out of the list of tab names. $K$8 holds the column the information sits in. I think my problem lies within the MATCH element of the formula. I've used this to find the row the word "Total" sits in which is the same row as the information I require sits in. "Total" is always found in column F of the template. I want the cell, on the summary page, with the sheet name in to feed into this part of the equation so I don't have to edit the sheet name by hand over 400 times.

I don't know much about excel formulas and what I've done so far is from looking stuff up online and trying it out.

Sorry if I haven't explained it very well.

Any help would be really appreciated.

I've tried the following:

```
=INDIRECT("'" & SUBSTITUTE($D14," ","") & "'!" & $I$8& MATCH("Total", "'" & SUBSTITUTE($D14," ","") & "'!" & $F:$F,0))
```

But this feeds column F from the summary page into the MATCH argument not column F from the sheet.

I then tried to include $F:$F with in the "", but I just get #VALUE out - See below:

```
=INDIRECT("'" & SUBSTITUTE($D14," ","") & "'!" & $I$8& MATCH("Total", "'" & SUBSTITUTE($D14," ","") & "'!$F:$F",0))
```

I've tried to use Vlookup, but I'm not sure how to use it for what i need or if its relevant.

Some other variations:

Taking $ out of referencing column F - #VALUE error:

```
    =INDIRECT("'" & SUBSTITUTE($D14," ","") & "'!" & $I$8& MATCH("Total","'" & SUBSTITUTE($D14," ","") & "'!F:F",0))
```

Removing ' ' around substitute (which gives sheet name) - #VALUE error:

```
    =INDIRECT("'" & SUBSTITUTE($D14," ","") & "'!" & $I$8& MATCH("Total","'" & SUBSTITUTE($D14," ","") & "'!F:F",0))
```

Removing ' ' around substitute (which gives sheet name) and $- #VALUE error:

```
    =INDIRECT("'" & SUBSTITUTE($D14," ","") & "'!" & $I$8& MATCH("Total", SUBSTITUTE($D14," ","") & "!F:F",0))
```

Comment: For each indirect reference to a range you need to use a new INDIRECT function, so for both the INDEX and **inside** the MATCH range you need to add an INDIRECT reference. If you better explain the structure of the tabs it may be unnecessary to use indirect even. Look here for an example of avoiding INDIRECT: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76670006/12634230